# Linux how to highlight every occurrance of a word.

Tags: linux

how do I highlight every occurrence of a word, Linux? I have tried to show the contents of my file but I don't know how to highlight specific words! please help!!

Comment: http://kassiopeia.juls.savba.sk/~garabik/software/grc.html

Answer (score 0):

You might use the search feature of 'more':
$ more filename.txt
Then type 
/word
and press Return. Navigate the file with arrow keys, move to the next occurrence with n.